# Error al insertar datos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form name="datos" action="TP 371 Orangel.php" method="post">
      Nombre:&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" size="15" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,}" name='nombre' id='nombre' required><br><br>
      CI/RIF:&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" size="11" name="ID" id="ID" required><br><br>
      Ciudad:&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,}" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" required><br><br>
      URB:&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" size="30" name="URB" id="URB"><br><br>
      Calle:&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" name="calle" id="calle" required><br><br>
      N°:&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="number" size="3" name="numero" id="numero" min="1" max="999" required><br><br>
      Correo:&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="email" size="30" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="ejemplo@gmail.com" required multiple><br><br>
      Telefono:&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="tel" size="12" name="telefono" id="telefono"><br><br>
      Tipo de mercancia que desea proteger:<input type="text" name="mercancia" id="mercancia"><br><br>
     ¿Incluye protecci&oacute;n ejecutiva(personal)?
    <select name="proteccion ejecutiva">
        <option value="Si">Si
        <option value="No">No
    </select><br><br>
    Describa el tipo de protecci&oacute;n que desea recibir:<br>
    <textarea name="descripcion del servicio" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"><input type="reset" value="Borrar">

<?php
    include("conexion2.php");
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $id = $_POST["ID"];
    $ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];
    $urb = $_POST["URB"];
    $calle = $_POST["calle"];
    $num = $_POST["numero"];
    $correo = $_POST["correo"];
    $tel = $_POST["telefono"];
    $mer = $_POST["mercancia"];
    $pro = $_POST["proteccion_ejecutiva"];
    $des = $_POST["descripcion_del_servicio"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO cliente(Nombre,CI/RIF,Ciudad,URB,Calle,NumHab,Mail,Tel,Mercan,Protejec,Descrip) VALUES('$nombre','$id','$ciudad','$urb','$calle','$num','$correo','$tel','$mer','$pro','$des')";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

    if($resultado){
        echo "Insercion exitosa";
    }else{
        echo "Insercion fallida";
    }
?>
```

//arcivo de conexion "conecion2.php"

```
<?php
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","@orangel18","transvalsa");
    if($conexion){
        echo "Conexion exitosa";
        }else{
            echo "Conexion fallida";
        }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Que error te da exactamente?

Comment: Te aconsejo que le eches un ojo a PDO, es una version posterior mas fiable pudiendo aplicar una mejor seguridad de una manera más sencilla. Te dejo un enlace donde tienes todo la inoformacion necesaria:   http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php

Comment: JDev cuando envio los datos desde el formulario me muestra por pantalla "Insercion fallida"

Comment: Usa `$conexion->error()` para ver que error exactamente te da la bbdd. Me da que ese CI/RIF tiene la culpa. http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php

Comment: veo que en tu query usas `$conexion` pero `$conexion` existe hasta despues del bloque de código del alta, por que?

Comment: @shadow creo que ha copiado los trozos de codigo sin orden.

Comment: precisamente, por que también veo un include conexion2 que no usa después; entonces sería mejor que arregle la pregunta

Comment: Listo amigos, gracias por su ayuda. El error estaba en el atributo CI/RIF en "/".

Answer (score 6):

noto 2 cosas raras en el código.
Primero:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cliente(Nombre,CI/RIF,Ciudad,URB,Calle,NumHab,Mail,Tel,Mercan,Protejec,Descrip) VALUES('$nombre','$id','$ciudad','$urb','$calle','$num','$correo','$tel','$mer','$pro','$des')";
```

El nombre del segundo campo, CI/RIF crería que no puedes usar el "/" en el nombre. El intérprete de cógido que uso me lo marcó como caracter especial.

Segundo: veo que antes de insertar los datos, no te estas conectando a la base. Lo haces después. Te recomiendo hacer

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","@orangel18","transvalsa");
if($conexion){
 echo "Conexion exitosa";

$query = "INSERT INTO cliente(Nombre,CI/RIF,Ciudad,URB,Calle,NumHab,Mail,Tel,Mercan,Protejec,Descrip) VALUES('$nombre','$id','$ciudad','$urb','$calle','$num','$correo','$tel','$mer','$pro','$des')";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);

      if($resultado){
                echo "Insercion exitosa";
                    }else{
                    echo "Insercion fallida";
                    }

      }
      else{
        echo "Conexion fallida";
      }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Saludos, son 3 archivos uno .htm donde esta el formulario y dos .php, por eso agrego el include("conexion2.php").

Comment: Si, esta bien, tendríamos un .html que sería el que nos muestras, luego al enviar el formulario los datos se van por POST a "TP 371 Orangel.php" No es recomendable usar espacios para los nombres de los archivos, en todo caso "TP_371_Orangel.php". 
Lo que preguntan arriba es, porque incluyes un conexion.php , donde normalmente se guardan los datos, "host", "user", "pass","database", para no tener que estar colocandolos manualmente, si cuando haces la conexión a la base de datos los pasas en forma manual. O los pasas por parámetros, o los escribís.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda amigo, en efecto el error esta en el atributo CI/RIF

Comment: Me quedo tranquilo. Entonces. Un abrazo.

Answer (score 0):

hay que saber que error te da para ver en que ayudarte, lo mejor sería que hicieras algo con try/catch, lo otro, el archivo del action, evita que tenga espacios.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)){

include("conexion2.php");
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$id = $_POST["ID"];
$ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];
$urb = $_POST["URB"];
$calle = $_POST["calle"];
$num = $_POST["numero"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$tel = $_POST["telefono"];
$mer = $_POST["mercancia"];
$pro = $_POST["proteccion_ejecutiva"];
$des = $_POST["descripcion_del_servicio"];
$query = "INSERT INTO cliente(Nombre,CI/RIF,Ciudad,URB,Calle,NumHab,Mail,Tel,Mercan,Protejec,Descrip) VALUES('$nombre','$id','$ciudad','$urb','$calle','$num','$correo','$tel','$mer','$pro','$des')";

    try {
        $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();

    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por aportar! no todas las preguntas se deben responder, y menos cuando estan incompletas. mira por favor [answer]

Comment: Gracias @gbiachi, lo tendré en cuenta.